# Parsing JSON in Objective-C using NSPredicates on Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nspredicate

I have the following JSON within an array(array name - banksList) from which I want to get the branch names of "ORIENTAL BANK OF COMMERCE":

```
<__NSArrayM 0x600000a4e820>(
{
    ADDRESS = "PLOT NO.C/3/10-B,GIDCOPP. ASHOPALAV GUEST HOUSE,";
    BANK = "BANK OF INDIA";
    BRANCH = "ANKLESHWAR INDUSTRIAL ESTATE";
    CITY = ANKALESHWAR;
    CONTACT = 2646226779;
    DISTRICT = ANKALESHWAR;
    IFSC = BKID0003003;
    "MICR CODE" = 393013051;
    STATE = GUJARAT;
    "_id" = 57cad024eae65540465771e5;
},
{
    ADDRESS = "C-5/1 GIDC RAVI KIRAN COMPX,VARIA CHATR RASTE,RAVI KIRAN COMPX, NH-8,ANKALESHWAR";
    BANK = "ORIENTAL BANK OF COMMERCE";
    BRANCH = "ANKLESHWAR-GUJRAT";
    CITY = ANKALESHWAR;
    CONTACT = 222123;
    DISTRICT = ANKALESHWAR;
    IFSC = ORBC0100736;
    "MICR CODE" = 393022051;
    STATE = GUJARAT;
    "_id" = 57cad02aeae655404658565c;
},
{
    ADDRESS = "KENDRIYA VIDYALAYA,13,,GANDHAR TOWN,ONGC TOWN,ANKALESHWAR";
    BANK = "ORIENTAL BANK OF COMMERCE";
    BRANCH = "ANKLESHWAR-EC KENDRIYA VIDYALAY";
    CITY = ANKALESHWAR;
    CONTACT = 232399;
    DISTRICT = ANKALESHWAR;
    IFSC = ORBC0105134;
    "MICR CODE" = 393022052;
    STATE = GUJARAT;
    "_id" = 57cad02aeae6554046585c43;
}
)
```

I tried doing:

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.bank contains %@", @"ORIENTAL BANK OF COMMERCE"];
banksList = [banksList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
branchNamesArray = [banksList valueForKey:@"BRANCH"];
```

My predicate doesn't seem to be working. Whenever I do filteredArrayUsingPredicate I get empty array back. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps `"self.BANK contains %@"`? Keys are case-sensitive.

Comment: Ahhh, that was it. Thanks @rmaddy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys are case-sensitive. Your predicate needs to be:

```
@"self.BANK contains %@"
```